# OLEDB excel insert unwanted character( ' )

Tags: c#, excel, odbc, oledb, insert-update

After insert in excel formula bar i got unwanted character `'` which restricts the field type like date to convert in specific format

```
query="INSERT INTO [book$] ([Book Name]) VALUES ('" + txtbookname.Text +"')";
```

This value is of string type after insert

For example: if i have inserted `I AM` in excel cell it will be the same.

But when going to *edit* that cell it shows `'I AM`. I dont want that `'` character at start

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: Does the single-quote show in the Excel *cell*, or just in the address bar when the cell is active?

Comment: To prevent typing difficulties and injection vulnerabilities, I recommend using OleDb's builting prepared-statement capabilities (IIRC). This makes it easier to _correctly_ assemble SQL statements, while specifying the _type_ of values

Comment: @DavidW that's the "cell edit field" (hit F2). Address bars are for browsers.

Comment: @sehe But, amazingly, you knew what I meant, didn't you? Good grief, some people here lose sight of the forest for the trees.

Comment: @DavidW They do? That probably has to do with people adding confusion in their explanations :) Seriously, I think on SO it really helps a lot to encourage _proper_ explanation. People coming here, tend to _already_ be confused without our help. Perhaps on [SU] or [Ask Ubuntu] things may balance out differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'` (like you almost said) indicates that the cell is of the text type.

In short, for text values, don't sweat it: this is just Excel's way of saying "this is a text content, not a formula or anything". It doesn't show up anyway. (Historical note: I believe this convention stems from original Lotus 123 compatibility, if memory serves).

This is to prevent things from going wrong (imagine if you inserted the text `=3*7`, should it be interpreted as a formula?).

Now, I haven't used Excel with the OleDB provider before, but I'm almost sure that you can get the desired effect by actually inserting a date (or number, or ...), instead of a string value. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO [book$] ([Copies]) VALUES (42)
```

Would insert the cell content `42`

```
INSERT INTO [book$] ([Copies]) VALUES ('42')
```

Would insert the cell content `'42`

Comment: @user3600403 perhaps, like I said, I'm not using Excel. Do you happen to have something worthwhile to share? Your claim isn't exactly crystal clear (in fact, `'123'` is different, so you probably mean that you don't see a different result _in a particular scenario_. Besides we cannot guess that scenario, did you try something else, like maybe `'''123'` to encode a cell value of `'123`?)

Comment: I wrote a simple VBA Macro to fix it and renamed it to .xlsm. Not a beautyful Solution, but its ok